# Trouble finding the matrix form of potential energy in small oscillations (Goldstein linear triatomic molecule example)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring, oscillators, coupled-oscillators

I'm currently trying to learn small oscillations, I kind of comprehend the general theory, but I'm having hard times finding the matrix forms of the potential and kinetic energy. I have been following the Goldstein book, but it doesn't give any explanation about this step, and I'm pretty sure it's obvious, but I can't seem to get it.

The problem is:

[image]

Starting from the potential energy:

\begin{equation}
V=\frac{k}{2}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}-b\right)^{2}+\frac{k}{2}\left(x_{3}-x_{2}-b\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
Coordinate relative to equilibrium position,
\begin{equation}
\eta_{i}=x_{i}-x_{0 i}
\end{equation}
where,
\begin{equation}
x_{02}-x_{01}=b=x_{03}-x_{02}
\end{equation}
the potential energy is reduced to:
\begin{equation}
V=\frac{1}{2} k\left(\eta_{2}-\eta_{1}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2} k\left(\eta_{3}-\eta_{2}\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
Developing
\begin{equation}
V=\frac{1}{2} k\left(\eta_{2}^{2}-2 \eta_{2} \eta_{1}+\eta_{2}^{2}+\eta_{3}^{2}-\eta_{2}^{2}+2 \eta_{3} \eta_{2}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
V=\frac{1}{2}k\left(\eta_{1}^{2}+2 \eta_{2}^{2}+\eta_{3}^{2}-2 \eta_{1} \eta_{2}-2 \eta_{2} \eta_{3}\right)
\end{equation}
I understand till here, what I don't know is how I'm supposed to pass this to the Matrix form. Specifically:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{V}=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
k & -k & 0 \\
-k & 2 k & -k \\
0 & -k & k
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Any specification, help or tip will be very much appreciated.

Comment: the matrix elements are $\mathbf V{ij}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_{i}}\left( \dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x_{j}}\right) $

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed, but I'm really supposed to calculate each element by that formula. Why I'm doing all the previous steps to arrive to $V=\frac{1}{2} k\left(\eta_{1}^{2}+2 \eta_{2}^{2}+\eta_{3}^{2}-2 \eta_{1} \eta_{2}-2 \eta_{2} \eta_{3}\right)$ then?

Comment: $\eta_i$ are the coordinates relative to equilibrium position , replace in the above equation x by $\eta$ you obtain the same matrix. notice that the stiffness matrix is always symmetric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your potential form:

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
V=\frac{1}{2}k\left(\eta_{1}^{2}+2 \eta_{2}^{2}+\eta_{3}^{2}-2 \eta_{1} \eta_{2}-2 \eta_{2} \eta_{3}\right)
\end{equation}

We define the vector
$$
\vec \eta = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1\\
\eta_2\\
\eta_3 
\end{pmatrix}; \,\,
\text{ and }\,\,
\vec \eta^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1 &
\eta_2 &
\eta_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The potential of Eq.(1) is then written as:
\begin{align}
V =& 
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1 &
\eta_2 &
\eta_3
\end{pmatrix} 
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
k & -k & 0 \\
-k & 2 k & -k \\
0 & -k & k
\end{array}\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta_1\\
\eta_2\\
\eta_3 
\end{pmatrix}\\
=& \vec \eta^T \mathbf{V}\vec{\eta}
\end{align}

This is the definition of matix potential.